# Rebasing a branch gives me a non fast forward error

Tags: git, github

Basically I've a `feature` branch and a `master` branch.
Here is the graph:

[image]

What I want to do is update the `feature` branch from the `master` branch without doing a merge commit on the `feature` branch (basically 'move' the first commit of the branch to 'master 9') .
So I've tried the the following commands:

```
git checkout feature
git rebase master
git push
```

But after the push, git returns an error.

```
! [rejected]        feature -> feature (non-fast-forward)
error: failed to push some refs to '...'
hint: Updates were rejected because the tip of your current branch is behind
hint: its remote counterpart. Integrate the remote changes (e.g.
hint: 'git pull ...') before pushing again.
hint: See the 'Note about fast-forwards' in 'git push --help' for details.
```

And if I execute the suggested `git pull`, after a `git push` my repository locks like this:
[image]

Which it's not what I wanted.
I've already tried using the parameter `--rebase` with the command `git pull`, but unfortunately the result is this:

[image]

I just want to the 'initial commit' from the `feature` branch to be the commit `master 9` but I've already tried anything without executing `git push --force` (which does work).

Can anyone explain to me why I need to use the force parameter to push the changes to the server?

Comment: The first three commands are all that is needed. You need to push force because `git rebase` rolls back your changes, puts the commits from the fresh branch (master), then applies your changes on top of those, effectively rewriting history.

Comment: `git rebase` is a local command. The error indicates the remote repository has some new commits that the local repository doesn't have yet. Run `git pull origin -r feature` to fix the error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rebase fundamentally works by *copying* commits.  You have some chain of commits:

```
...--A--B--F--G   <-- master
         \
          C--D--E   <-- feature
```

(this is a similar drawing to the graph image you posted: mine is just sideways with newer commits towards the right, vs yours with newer commits towards the top).  Some of these commits are now old-and-lousy and you'd like to replace them with new-and-improved commits.  In particular, commit `C` is based off `B` and you'd like a copy of `C`, which we can call `C'`, that points to `G` rather than `B`.  After that, you'd like to make a copy of `D`, which we can call `D'`, that is based off the copy you just made, `C'`.  This repeats for `E` as well:

```
                C'-D'-E'  <-- (new-and-improved-feature)
               /
...--A--B--F--G   <-- master
         \
          C--D--E   <-- feature
```

Now, each commit in Git actually has a unique hash ID: a big ugly string of letters and digits that no human wants to deal with.  That's OK, we mostly don't *have* to deal with them: that's why we have a computer, after all.  We have *Git* remember these commit hash IDs.  The *branch names* in particular remember the hash ID of the *last* commit in the series, at the tip of the branch.

So, having made these copies, we now yank the name `feature` off of commit `E` and make it point instead to copy `E'`:

```
                C'-D'-E'  <-- feature
               /
...--A--B--F--G   <-- master
         \
          C--D--E   [abandoned]
```

This all happens in *your* repository.  The other repository, over at `origin`, doesn't have the new commits at all yet.

You now use `git push` to have your Git call up *their* Git.  Your Git sends them your three shiny new replacement commits, `C'-D'-E'`, which they place in quarantine for a moment (in case they reject them) but which are now logically in their repository:

```
                C'-D'-E'  [ready]
               /
...--A--B--F--G   <-- master
         \
          C--D--E   <-- feature
```

Note that *their* name `feature`—which is their name, not your name—still points to commit `E`.

Your Git now says: *Please, if it's OK, make your name `feature` point to commit `E'`.*  Their Git looks at this picture and says: *Whoa there buddy, that's **not** OK!  If I do that, I'll forget the hash ID of existing commit `E`!  I'll never be able to find that commit again!*

> ```
> ! [rejected]        feature -> feature (non-fast-forward)
> ```

This means *Whoa there, **not** OK, I'd lose some commits!*

But losing some commits is *exactly what you want them to do*.  It's what your Git already did: you can't find your original commits any more; you've thrown them into the recycling bin, in favor of the shiny new commits you just made.

You now must tell that other Git, over on `origin`, to do the same thing.  To do that, you have two options:

- `--force`: this says *Set your `feature`!*  There is no checking; you just send them a forceful command, instead of a polite request.  They obey, or don't, according to whatever rules they have for their branches.  If you're authorized—and you probably are—they just obey.
- `--force-with-lease`: this has your Git say *I think your `feature` points to old commit `E`, that is now outdated.  If so, make your `feature` point to new commit `E'` instead.*  Here, they'll answer *OK* if your Git is correct and *no* if your Git is wrong.

Obviously, `--force-with-lease` is safer, in some sense: if your Git is wrong about them, you'll get an error back.

The interesting questions you should ask here are:

- Where does my Git get its idea of what their Git's `feature` points to?
- When and why would their `feature` point somewhere I didn't expect?

Those questions are answered here on StackOverflow, if you go looking.  (So is your original question.)